# TensorFlow split integer sequence everywhere that a given int occurs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, split

I am training a character-level model, currently experimenting with adding more features to the character embeddings. Namely, concatenating the embedding of the word it is in. So I need to be able to detect, **using TensorFlow ops**, where spaces occur and unstack.

I.e. suppose the integer for a space is 2, and the tensor is `[3,5,2,3,2,1,1,1]`. Then I need to unstack this to `[3,5], [2], [3], [2], [1,1,1]`. I can't find anything in the documentation to do this; help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Daniel - please show what you've tried so far. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask